# angular2+: how to loop through the values of a three state (indeterminate) checkbox

Tags: angular, checkbox

I use angular 2+, bootstrap4, no jQuery

---

The reason why the checkbox needs to have three states, is because we use it to perform a query on the back-end (as one of a number of criteria) as follows:

- true: all items that are sold
- false: all items that are not sold
- null: don't use this criterion to filter

---

I managed to initialize the checkbox with indeterminate as it's initial value:

- html.component:

```
<input class="form-control" type="checkbox" formControlName="issold" (change)="onCheckboxIssoldChange($event)"
                                                   [indeterminate]="true" #issold>
```

- ts.component

```
set indeterminate(value: boolean) {
        this.elem.nativeElement.indeterminate = value;
    }
```

---

To loop through the values I tried two approaches:

1. using ElemenRef

```
    constructor(private elem: ElementRef) {} 

    indeterminateCounterSold : number = 0; 

    @ViewChild('issold', { static: true }) issold: ElementRef; 

    onCheckboxIssoldChange(e) {
this.indeterminateCounterSold++;
verifyTristateValue(this.indeterminateCounterSold);}  

verifyTristateValue(numberOfClicks: number)
    this.elem.nativeElement.indeterminate = true; // try version 1a
    this.issold.nativeElement.indeterminate = true; // try version 1b
    }
```

2. Using the (change)-function

reference: [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/i/indeterminate/)

```
onCheckboxIssoldChange(checkbox: any) {
  if (checkbox.readOnly) {
  checkbox.checked = checkbox.readOnly = false;
}
else if (!checkbox.checked) {
  checkbox.readOnly = checkbox.indeterminate = true;
}
}
```

... and variations on both.

Comment: Just to be clear your aim is to have a checkbox with three states: true, false and untouched? i.e. once the user has clicked the checkbox, they will only be able to toggle between two states, but you don't want the "untouched" state to count as either true or false?

Comment: No, that's exactly the problem. that's what I have now. Once the user start clicking he should be able to get back to the indeterminate state (you know, visually, the slim vertical line, in the box). Else, once he has clicked the box in a previous query, he/she would have to reload the page for a following query where he/she doesn't want this criterion to be used. It's actually just a checkbox of several, next to input fields, in a larger form.

Answer (score 0):

The second method actually does work if you apply it correctly. Currently I was only passing the event on itself, without grabbing the checkbox.

so the html remains unchanged, and we make sure to define the target of the event

```
onCheckboxIssoldChange(checkboxEventChange: any) {
var checkbox = checkboxEventChange.target;
  if (checkbox.readOnly) {
  checkbox.checked = checkbox.readOnly = false;
}
else if (!checkbox.checked) {
  checkbox.readOnly = checkbox.indeterminate = true;
}
}
```